# Update Nested state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with state like. I am creating dynamic form, all is working fine but I want to reset the form value once submit button clicked.
for that i have a helper function called *resetForm()* , but unfortunately the logic is not working.
can anybody help with this..

```
state = {
    expenseForm: {
        date: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'date',
                placeholder: 'Enter Date..'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                isDate: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        category: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: !this.props.loading ? transformCategory(this.props.categories): null
            },
            value: transformCategory(this.props.categories)[0].value,
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 4
            },
            valid: true,
            touched: false
        },
        description: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Enter Description..'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 6
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        amount: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'number',
                placeholder: 'Enter amount..'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 1
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        }
    },
    formIsValid: false
}
```

[React Component code link](https://github.com/RAHULRAJSONU/stack-overflow/blob/master/CreateExpense.js)

Comment: Could you include your component and the `resetForm` method in the question?

Comment: And tell us what the actual issue is. Saying that it's "not working" doesn't help us, tell us the expected behaviour, the incorrect behaviour you're currently getting, any error messages (e.g. console errors) that you're getting, and so on.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply, I have given the link to the component. please check once

Answer (score 1):

You could have a function `getInitialState` that returns an object you can use as initial state for your component. When you need to reset the component state, you can use `setState` with the result of `getInitialState` again.

**Example**

```js
function getInitialState() {
  return {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = getInitialState();

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  resetForm = () => {
    this.setState(getInitialState());
  };

  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Email: <input name="email" value={email} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          Password: <input name="password" type="password" value={password} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.resetForm}> Reset </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```